# Could not find declaration file for modules 'laravel-mix' in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to use Laravel mix and installed node modules but when I import Laravel mix by-

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
```

it says-

> could not find declaration file for modules 'laravel-mix'

Any suggestion please?

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.copyDirectory('resources/backend', 'public/backend');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/backend/js');
```

Comment: what version of laravel are you using? in older versions it doesnt support laravel-mix.

Comment: @sunder s:Laravel 6

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the `node_modules` folder and reinstall dependencies using your dependency manager

```
npm install
```

---

If still not working, send `package.json` content